# How to set a custom font from the assets folder to the title of an Actionbar in Android?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, typeface, spannablestring, android-typeface

I am trying to set a custom font `Dosis-Medium.otf` which is placed in the `asssets` folder under a `subfolder font`. I am trying to use the following code but it gives me an error

`The constructor TypefaceSpan(Profile, String) is undefined`. Please guide me step by step where I am going wrong.

My code snippet is as follows:

```
   SpannableString s = new SpannableString("My Title");
   s.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan(this, "Dosis-Medium.otf"), 0, s.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
   ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
   actionBar.setTitle(s);
```

Comment: hi ann, which error you are getting ?? can you please post it here?

Comment: I mean when I type the command in the second line above I get a red cross in the editor (eclipse) with the following message `the constructor TypefaceSpan(Profile, String) is undefined`

Comment: s.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan(this, "Dosis-Medium.otf"), 0, s.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE); in this line?

Comment: got solution or not??

Comment: You have to copy this class https://gist.github.com/twaddington/b91341ea5615698b53b8 into your application as default TypefaceSpan class don't have this constructor. By the way I was also in search of something that and your question helped :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hi as you are getting error **The constructor TypefaceSpan(Profile, String) is undefined**

please visit for TypefaceSpan doc

https://gist.github.com/twaddington/b91341ea5615698b53b8

as the constructor is defined a s

```
TypefaceSpan(Context context, String typefaceName)
```

please pass Context properly of yours activity/app

as i think you are using the code from

http://www.tristanwaddington.com/2013/03/styling-the-android-action-bar-with-a-custom-font/

Comment: I pasted the whole class into my application but I still get that error. can u help me?

Comment: please get the activity/application context and pass it to constructor rather than this as this will give currently running class while you need the current context

Comment: like have a try with YoursActivity.getApplicationContext()